# Little confusion with tab bar controller and tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I want to provide an opportunity to switch between 3 view controllers.I don't use navigation controller.Instead,I prefer tab bar.Here in xcode we have tab bar controller and tab bar.What are the purposes for providing independent tab bar object?I mean when you drag tab bar Controller it creates controller and 2 items and they already have tab bar.Doesn't it mean I can use it without view controller or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the UITabBar is an independent pre-defined UI element you can use wherever you want. Using it in combination with a `UITabBarController` gives you the benefits of handling events related to the `UITabBar` easily, since you don't need to implement most of the logic yourself.

Comment: wherever? in which way I can access independent tab bar?

Comment: like posting a tag on it and then call somewhere in controller UITabBar *tabBar = (UITabBar*)[self.view viewWithTag:tag]?

Comment: because it is not possible to create IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

UITabBar is inherit from UIView and while UITabBarController is inherit from UIViewController and responses to the protocols UITabBarDelegate and NSCoding.

Moreover UITabBarController provide automatic mechanism and logic - the other is more flexible in case you have to implement the things differently.

Comment: Good answer also, but I wanted to hear they can exist on their own